# OpenCV MATLAB: How to draw a line having a particular Intensity profile?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

Below is an arbitrary hand-drawn Intensity profile of a **line** in an image:
[image]

The task is to draw the **line**.  The profile can be approximated to an arc of a circle or ellipse. 
This I am doing for camera calibration. Since I do not have the actual industrial camera, I am trying to simulate the correction needed for calibration.

The question can be rephrased as I want pixel values which will follow a plot similar to the above. I want to do this using program (Preferably using opencv) and not manually enter these values because I have thousands of pixels in the line.
An algorithm/pseudo code will suffice.  Also please note that I do not have any actual Intensity profile, otherwise I would have read those values.

**When will you encounter such situation** ?

Suppose you take a picture (assuming complete white) from a Camera, your object being placed on table, and camera just above it in vertical direction. The light coming on the center of the picture vertically downward from the camera will be stronger in intensity as compared to the light reflecting at the edges. You measure pixel values across any line in the Image, you will find intensity curve like shown above. Since I dont have camera for the time being, I want to emulate this situation. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly image processing, rather image generation... but anyways.

Since you want an arc, we still need three points on that arc, lets take the first, middle and last point (key characteristics in my opinion):

```
N = 100; % number of pixels
x1 = 1;
x2 = floor(N/2);
x3 = N;

y1 = 242;
y2 = 255;
y3 = 242;
```

and now draw a circle arc that contains these points.
This problem is already discussed here for matlab: http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297070

```
x21 = x2-x1; y21 = y2-y1;
x31 = x3-x1; y31 = y3-y1;
h21 = x21^2+y21^2; h31 = x31^2+y31^2;
d = 2*(x21*y31-x31*y21);
a = x1+(h21*y31-h31*y21)/d; % circle center x
b = y1-(h21*x31-h31*x21)/d; % circle center y
r = sqrt(h21*h31*((x3-x2)^2+(y3-y2)^2))/abs(d); % circle radius
```

If you assume the middle value is always larger (and thus it's the upper part of the circle you'll have to plot), you can draw this with:

```
x = x1:x3;
y = b+sqrt(r^2-(x-a).^ 2);
plot(x,y);
```

you can adjust the visible window with

```
xlim([1 N]);
ylim([200 260]);
```

which gives me the following result:
[image: arc]